# Why is the Startup class of Asp.net Core not derived from an interface or abstract class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my understanding, `Startup` must have `Configure` method. `Startup` is then registered in `Program.Main`.

## Question

As `Startup` must have `Configure`,  why is the `Startup` class of Asp.net Core not  derived from an interface or abstract class?

Comment: Duplicate of [Why is ASP.NET Core's Startup class not an interface or abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53254735/1220550) (could not mark it using a 'close' flag because the asker hasn't formally accepted the answer)

Comment: @PeterB: Thank you. But duplication should not be deleted.

Comment: A good explanation by David Fowler: https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/700097cca459c1e78c86